# Is it possible to create an action link for just one selection in the column of the grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an asp.net mvc "reservations" app. in c# where in a grid view I have a few statuses of the review process, like "new", "pending, "approved", "declined" along with details about each request.

Is it possible for just one review status ("Pending", for example, ) to be an action link, so a user can click on it and see a checklist of reservation requirements.

Right now I have all statuses as an action link:
`columns.Template(o =>
                {
                    %>
                    <%= Html.ActionLink(o.Status, "Details", new { id = o.ID })%>
                    <%
                }).Title("Status").Width(50);`
But I need just one of them, "pending" to be active, and others just to be displayed in a view.

Thank you very much for any help!

Here is a more complete code:
`columns.Bound(o => o.Status);
            columns.Template(o =>
                {
                    %>
                    <% if (o.Status == "New") { %>
                        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Pending", "ReservationRequests")) { %>
                            <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
                            <%= Html.Hidden("ID", o.ID) %>
                            
                        <% } %>
                    <% } %>

```
                <%
            }).Title(string.Empty).Width(50);

        columns.Template(o =>
            {
            %>

                <% if (o.Status == "Declined" | o.Status == "New" | o.Status == "Pending")
                   { %>
                    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Approve", "ReservationRequests")) { %>
                        <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
                        <%= Html.Hidden("ID", o.ID) %>
                        <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="submit" />
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>
                <%
            }).Title(string.Empty).Width(50);
        columns.Template(o =>
            {
                %>
                <% if (o.Status == "Approved" | o.Status == "New" | o.Status == "Pending")
                   { %>
                    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Decline", "ReservationRequests")) { %>
                        <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
                        <%= Html.Hidden("ID", o.ID) %>
                        <input type="submit" value="Decline" class="submit" />
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>
                <%
            }).Title(string.Empty).Width(50);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is [Conditional Rendering](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx). There are plenty of examples out there. But you could just do something like:

```
@if (status == "pending") {
    columns.Template(o => { %> <%= Html.ActionLink(o.Status, "Details", new { id = o.ID })%> <% }).Title("Status").Width(50);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I need. Just to clarify: at first a have a status "new" in a status column, that after "pending" is clicked, turns to "pending". The code for this is:

Comment: Template(o =>
                {
                    %>
                    <% if (o.Status == "New") { %>
                        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Pending", "ReservationRequests")) { %>
                            <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
                            <%= Html.Hidden("ID", o.ID) %>
                            <input type="submit" value="Pending" class="submit" />

Comment: How is it possible to have the "pending" turn to be an action link? The <if (o.status == "pending"> condition works, but it creates a separate column in the grid, and I need the "pending" action link to be in the same column as all other statuses. Thank you!

Comment: My answer was more of a general concept for you to build from. But would it be possible for you to post all of your relevant code into your original post? It would help to get a better idea of what condition you need to check for.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your initial if statements, but can't you just insert another check inside each of them to see if o.Status == "Pending"? then insert an action link? Like: using (Html.BeginForm("Approve", "ReservationRequests")) 
        {
            if (o.Status == "Pending")
            {
                ...
                columns.Template(o => { %> <%= Html.ActionLink(o.Status, "Details", new { id = o.ID })%> <% }).Title("Status").Width(50);
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }  it's difficult to format in this lil box, sorry